In package `factoextra` PCA , in given varialbe , how to know which individual's contribution is high
In package factoextra Principle Component Analysis (PCA),facto_summarize can get variable or individual summary information . How can I get variable and individual summary in one step ?
I mean , want to know in given varialbe ,which individual's contribution is high ?
For example , in below code  variable X100m 's contribution  is 11.756423, then which individual 's contribution  are high for 11.756423
library(factoextra)
data(decathlon2)
decathlon2.active <- decathlon2[1:23, 1:10]
res.pca <- prcomp(decathlon2.active,  scale = TRUE)


facto_summarize(res.pca, "var", axes = 1:3)[,-1]

